# Merging npz files

Tags: python, numpy, npz-file

I have a directory with a bunch of npz files that I want to merge into a single npz file. I know that I can technically open each file and concatenate each array inside of it, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require that.

I've found this solution:

```
import numpy as np

data_all = [np.load(fname) for fname in file_list]
merged_data = {}
for data in data_all:
    [merged_data.update({k: v}) for k, v in data.items()]
np.savez('new_file.npz', **merged_data)
```

but for some reason it does not actually merge the data, it just takes the data of the last npz file that was opened.

Comment: An `npz` is a zip archive of `npy` files, each of which contains an numpy array.  What exactly do you want?  A new npz with all the npy files?  What about name overlaps.  There may be an OS archive tool combine them.

Comment: In your dict based load and update, be careful about `key` values.  If you have a `a.npy` in several files, what is the 'merged' result supposed to be?

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge the data'?  Python `dict.update' over writes the `v` when `k` matches.  If you want to join arrays from different npz, you'll have to use the appropriate `concatenate`.

Comment: I want to make one single npz file that contains the concatenated data. But I'm wondering if it is possible to do so without explicitly saying so for each npy file.

Comment: So, basically, I want that a.npy from the first npz file and a.npy from the second npz file are concatenated. But in a general way for all npz files

Comment: There's no general mechanism.  I'd collect all like named `npy` arrays in lists (a `defaultdict might be handy), and after all are loaded, perform the concatenate on each list.  Then savez..

Answer (score 0):

I investigated a little bit more, and found the solution to my problem. First, before creating each npz file, I stored my data inside of a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'arr_0': arr_0, 'arr_1': arr_1}
```

Then I saved the data in the npz file with kwargs:

`np.savez_compressed('path/to/file/filename.npz', **data`)

After doing this for every npz file, I ended up with the directory mentioned at the beginning of my question. Then, in another python script, I opened all the files and stored their names in a list called `filenames`. Now, to the actual solution of my question, I did:

```
data_all = [np.load(fname) for fname in filenames]
merged_data = {}

for k in data_all[0].keys():
    merged_data[k] = np.concatenate(list(d[k] for d in data_all))
```